# Interface, Angular 5, Reactive Form

Tags: interface, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I have created an interface for login and getting and error when I am trying to compile it

**error :**Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'IAuth'. Property 'email' is missing in type 'FormGroup'

auth.ts

```
export interface IAuth{

    email : String;
    password : String;

}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { HomePage } from './../home/home';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';    
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
import { IAuth } from '../../models/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {
  userAuth : IAuth;
  constructor ( private formBuilder : FormBuilder)
               {
                 this.userAuth = formBuilder.group({
                  email : new FormControl('',Validators.required),
                  password : new FormControl('',Validators.required)
                 });
               }
}
```

Comment: Formbuilder will return type FormGroup object that you can't assign  to IAuth interface. since it is not a type of IAuth. change the type of userAuth to FormGroup

Comment: but how i can assign o map every field on FormGroup to Interface..? @Anto Antony.